# Multiline Replace via Regex

Tags: notepad++

i have a problem i have a textlist with some format:

```
Sticky_Forev:qapv4fmy@beta.samp-rp.ru/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82
```

i need this:

```
Sticky_Forev:qapv4fmy
```

i try

Find what: `(@[^@]*)@.*`
Replace with: `$1`

but never working for me. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first `@` at the begining:

Find what: `([^@]*)@.*`
Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex seems far too complex for what you seem to be asking.

Try this find: `(.*)@`

Edit
Are you aware of https://regex101.com?

Services like this help you write regex and learn while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler just replace this

```
              (.*)@.*
```

by

```
              \1
```

Upto what you want to retain, put them in bracket and rest all should be outside the bracket.